# How does Win8 classify a process as a "Background Process"? My app works in Win7 but shows no UI in Win8

Tags: c++, windows-8

My fairly normal MFC-based Windows application works fine on Windows 7.  But when I run it in Windows 8, no UI appears.  At first I thought it somehow wasn't launching properly, but eventually realized that if I bring up the Task Manager, it shows that my application *is* running but it's listed under the "Background processes" section.

What heuristics is Windows 8 running on a process to decide it is a "background process"?  Or is there something I can do--perhaps in the application manifest--to explicitly label my application as a *foreground* process?

I have tried running in Win7 and XP compatibility modes, to no avail.  I have tried several Win8 machines, all give the same result.

For what it's worth, this app is compiled with Visual Studio 2003 and I do not have the option of using a newer compiler.

I have googled things like "win8 background process" but all I'm getting are people who *want* to create a background process.  Some of the answers suggest that a background process has to be registered using the application manifest, but I double-checked my manifest and it definitely has nothing in it about being a background process.

Here's my manifest, in case you can see something off in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
<assemblyIdentity 
    version="1.0.0.0" 
    processorArchitecture="X86" 
    name="MyProductName"
    type="win32" 
/> 
    <description>My Product Description</description> 
    <dependency> 
        <dependentAssembly> 
            <assemblyIdentity 
                type="win32" 
                name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
                version="6.0.0.0" 
                processorArchitecture="X86" 
                publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" 
                language="*" 
            /> 
        </dependentAssembly> 
    </dependency> 
    <asmv3:trustInfo xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <asmv3:security>
            <asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
                <asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
            </asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
        </asmv3:security>
    </asmv3:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I will be opening a support incident with Microsoft to get their help if I can't find an answer here.  If it gets to that point, I'll certainly update this question with what I find.

Comment: Have you tried making a hello world program based off yours and see if it also fails to show up?

Comment: what happens if you change `uiAccess="false" ` to `uiAccess="true" `?

Comment: It is simply a process without a visible window.  Turn View + Group by Type off to avoid it confusing you.  Clearly you'll need to debug it.

Comment: Be careful with `uiAccess=true`, don't use it unless you **really** need it. There are consequences by enabling it, such as requiring the app to be code-signed, and disabling UIPI. Normal apps should work just fine with `uiAccess=false`.

Comment: @Yakk I do have a later version of the same program, built using VS2010, which runs fine on Win8.  But lots has changed over the intervening years so it's not a simple matter to determine what the important difference is.

Comment: @HansPassant This is embarrassing to admit, but I actually haven't stepped through it in a debugger yet on Win8!  Getting the build environment set up is not trivial.  But I think you're right, I should take the time.  Perhaps as people are suggesting here the bug is actually that it truly isn't displaying it's window, and thus Win8 is correct in classifying it as a background process.  I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: I'm saying "reduce the problem".  Copy the program's source.  Delete nearly everything, and reduce it to "hello world".  See if the problem still occurs.  Reduce the program until you can post it in its entirety in a post, and recreate the program from what you post (without any hidden state) and make sure it does reproduce the problem.  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure speculation on my part, as I can't find any documentation on this, but I suspect that something in MFC is failing, and the lack of a working UI is why Task Manager is classifying your app as a Background Process, since the user is not able to interact with it.

Comment: It appears you are right, that the problem is no UI is appearing (though not MFC's fault in this case).  In fact a breakpoint in WinMain never gets hit, so somehow the application is deadlocking early, perhaps while loading dlls...?  My application is not running yet, but you have answered my question and given me a direction to follow by showing it's not a case of Windows 8 mis-classifying my process.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm developing Windows 8 applications but not much knowledge of MFC development. so based on my knowledge MFC development is more similer to Silverlight development but Windows 8 development is more different than MFC development platform.

by the way, "**Classification of Background Process in Win 8**":

**The Process of application which is in suspend mode, that means the application is running but not showing any UI due to Desktop mode.**
to clarify my self on this point I checked once more by creating a tread in win 8 by XAML & C#, and made that thread as in suspend mode, only at that time that process showing as background process in task manager.

moreover that **"Specifically for Windows 8 only"** :

The process of any app shows as background process when Provided Resources to the app will decreases or will d-allocate those resources but still application is loaded and running...

This feature of Windows 8 is known as "Auto Resource allocation"...

sorry if you not find your answer here but i think this can help you to know **"Which process is classify as Background Process in Win 8"**